# Github single file download using shell script

Tags: python, github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am trying to make a source control enabled program.

My current Shell file

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/data_sync/projects/task1
/home/data_sync/projects/task1/bin/python program.py
```

I have set up a crontab to run this every day.

The trouble is every time I make an update I have to manually place the updated program.py file there.

```
wget -O program.py https://raw.githubusercontent.com/path/to/file/master/program.py
```

When this line was added it worked well if the repo is Public.

But with a private repo, it fails to download the file.

Any suggestions on how this can be done for a private repo.

I have linked the target machine's SSH key with the GitHub account.

Also, is it possible that the file is downloaded only if it has changed?